# How to get the username for the user authenticated to a network share

Tags: c#, security, networking

If I put a c# program on a share on a Windows server, it might be run by somebody who is logged in as a local user on a laptop. When they connect to the share, they have to authenticate with the share (entering username and password).

My question is, how can my program determine the username used to authenticate to the domain (not the username used to logon to the laptop)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx):

```
var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string username = user.Name;
```

Comment: I've tried WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, but this gives me the laptop workgroup\username not the username used to authenticate to the share.